# How to use filter with "jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget" when populating the option using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using the "jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget" in my application. One of the nice futures in the filter which will allow you to search for an option in the drop down menu.

The problem that I am having is when I populate the option using an AJAX call the filter option will no longer work.

the ajax request is correct and it populates the menu with no issue but when I type something in the filter box with in the "MultiSelect" option I it does not filter them..

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#lstBox2").multiselect().multiselectfilter({
        filter: function(event, matches){

            // find the first matching checkbox
            var first_match = $( matches[0] );
        }
    });


    $('#client').change( function(){

        $('#lstBox2').html('');

        $.getJSON("ajax/getCallTypes.php", {
                client_id: $(this).val()
            },function (data) {

                if ( ! data) 
                return; 

                $.each(data, function(i,v){

                    $('#lstBox2').append('<option value="'+ v.id +'">'+ v.name +'</option>'); 

                });

            }
        ).done(function(){

            $("#lstBox2").multiselect('refresh');

        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the `<option>` tags as jQuery objects (`$('<option>').text(v.name).val(v.id)`), instead of appending them as raw HTML?

Comment: no I did not. I don't know how I can do such a thing?

Comment: See the code in my previous comment: `$('<option>').text(v.name).val(v.id)` This gives you a jQuery object that you can then *append* to your *lstBox2*.